# Circular Buffer Implementation

Tags: c#, locking, circular-list

I'm implementing a "live analytics" feature and I need to always keep track of the last N items that were added to a collection so I figured I'd make a circular buffer since I couldn't find one.

I tried to figure out to use `Interlocked` but couldn't find out how to use `Increment` or `CompareExchange` in an obviously correct way - so I took the lock.

Review/advice is appreciated.

```
public class CircularBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly T[] _data;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private int _i = 0;
    private bool _isOneCycleFinished = false;
    private readonly int _size;

    public CircularBuffer(int size)
    {

        if (size < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(size)} cannot be negative");
        }
        _i = 0;
        _data = new T[size];
        _size = size;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Latest()
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterReadLock();
            if (!_isOneCycleFinished)
            {
                return _data.Take(_i).ToList();
            }
            return _data.Concat(_data).Skip(_i).Take(_size).ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }


    public void Add(T t)
    {
        try
        {
            _lock.EnterWriteLock();
            _i = (_i + 1)%_size;
            if (!_isOneCycleFinished && _i == 0)
            {
                _isOneCycleFinished = true;
            }
            _data[_i] = t;
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `Interlocked.Exchange(ref _i, (_i + 1) % _size);` and get rid of the local i variable.

Comment: What's the point of `_isOneCycleFinished`?

Comment: @eurotrash I want to return the data so far - it determines if I need to only fetch the first `_i` items or I need to return the `_size` items starting at `i`. If the buffer is of ints and of size 4 - It starts as `0000`, I add 1 and 2 and get `1200` - with `Latest` I expect to get `1,2`. Now if I add `3` `4` `5` `6` in - the buffer is at `5634`, I expect to get `3456`.

Comment: Is this class meant to be thread safe? (It's not.)

Comment: is this not just a queue of 4 elements, for which you can use ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: @eurotrash why not?

Comment: @Gareth the queue needs to be bounded in size.

Comment: @Uno no, because `_i + 1 % size` might be calculated in several threads at once. So I would exchange for the wrong value.

Comment: A useful bit of research : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460690(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum make sense. Anything like Thread.MemoryBarrier() to get the latest version without a lock?

Comment: @Uno that's even more terrifying and I'm not sure why it'd work - doesn't `MemoryBarrier` only require that the code isn't reordered? The goal of this CR question was to make the implementation _less_ tricky to understand - even the current implementation apparently isn't thread safe (eurotrash claims so).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well that was before you edited it. `Add()`'s write to `_isOneCycleFinished` and `Latest()`'s read of `_isOneCycleFinished` were not synchronised, nor were the writing and reading of `_i`.

Comment: I hate the current implementation :(

Answer (score 7):

Like @Gareth mentioned in his comment it would be perfect to use the `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

You answered `@Gareth the queue needs to be bounded in size` but where is the problem. We can just add a check to the `Add()` method and if the queue's size is equal to the bounded size we will just dequeue one item.

If the passed in `size` parameter of the constructor is `0` you will get a `DivideByZeroException` at `_i = (_i + 1)%_size;` and it doesn't really make sense to have a `CircularBuffer` with `size == 0`, does it ?

As you will notice in the adjusted code, I have placed the `_lock.EnterWriteLock();` outside of the `try..finally` [because what happens if the call to `EnterWriteLock()` fails ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7071103/2655508)

```
public class CircularBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<T> _data;
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private readonly int _size;

    public CircularBuffer(int size)
    {
        if (size < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(size)} cannot be negative or zero");
        }
        _data = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
        _size = size;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Latest()
    {
        return _data.ToArray();
    }

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        _lock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            if (_data.Count == _size)
            {
                T value;
                _data.TryDequeue(out value);
            }

            _data.Enqueue(t);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

although using a `ConcurrentQueue` is IMO the cleaner way I will post a solution using a generic array as well like so

```
public class CircularBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim slimLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    private readonly int capacity;
    private readonly T[] buffer;
    private readonly int upperBound;

    private int currentIndex = -1;
    private int currentStart = 0;

    public CircularBuffer(int size)
    {
        if (size < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(size)} cannot be negative nor zero");
        }

        buffer = new T[size];
        capacity = size;
        upperBound = size - 1;
    }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        slimLock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {

            if (IsFull || currentIndex == upperBound)
            {
                currentStart = FetchNextSlot(currentStart);
                IsFull = true;
            }

            currentIndex = FetchNextSlot(currentIndex);
            buffer[currentIndex] = value;

        }
        finally
        {
            slimLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }

    }

    public bool IsFull { get; private set; }

    private int FetchNextSlot(int value)
    {
        return (value + 1) % capacity;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Latest()
    {
        slimLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            return FetchItems().ToArray();
        }
        finally
        {
            slimLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> FetchItems()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> fetchedItems = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        if (IsFull)
        {
            return FetchItems(currentStart, upperBound);
        }
        return fetchedItems.Concat(FetchItems(0, currentIndex));
    }
    private IEnumerable<T> FetchItems(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            yield return buffer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be backwards? Wouldn't I be relying on implementation detail here (that ConcurrentQueue uses a circular buffer internally)? I'm making the queue too big and then removing one item from it.

Comment: What do you mean with `I'm making the queue too big and then removing one item from it` ? I don't get it.

Comment: Your circular buffer isn't actually a circular buffer, it's a bounded-in size queue. Since ConcurrentQueue is implemented using a circular buffer internally it _happens_ to work but there are no guarantees it will continue to do so in the future.

Comment: A queue is always implemented that it just guarantees that added items will be put to the tail and will be read from the head. Thats just the definition of a queue. What my implementation does is just using this feature to make it work like it does before but much cleaner. Why shouldn't this work in the future ? The `ConcurrentQueue` will always have a `Count` property , a `TryDequeue()` and `Enqueue()` method. The underlying details just don't matter here.

Comment: Right, but a CircularBuffer has other guarantees that are not explicitly preserved here - no dynamic memory allocations and fixed memory size. If ConcurrentQueue was implemented using a LinkedList for instance, or even as an array - these performance invariants would not be preserved.

Comment: @Heslacher I think there is a problem in your CircularBuffer implementation. `Latest` will return double the length when `currentStart=0 && IsFull`. I've made a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jnP2Lh

Comment: @Ross you are right. Edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the usage of the `ReaderWriteLockSlim` a little bit nicer and get rid of the try/catch block with two disposable helpers:

```
public class ReaderLockSlim : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lockSlim;

    public ReaderLockSlim(ReaderWriterLockSlim lockSlim) 
    { 
        _lockSlim = lockSlim; 
        _lockSlim.EnterReadLock();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _lockSlim.ExitReadLock();
    }
}

public class WriterLockSlim : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _lockSlim;

    public WriterLockSlim(ReaderWriterLockSlim lockSlim)
    {
        _lockSlim = lockSlim;
        _lockSlim.EnterWriteLock();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _lockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

---

**Example**

before:

> ```
> public IEnumerable<T> Latest()
> {
>     slimLock.EnterReadLock();
>     try
>     {
>         return FetchItems().ToArray();
>     }
>     finally
>     {
>         slimLock.ExitReadLock();
>     }
> }
> ```

after:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Latest()
{
    using (new ReaderLockSlim(slimLock)) 
    {
        return FetchItems().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - "using" is an interesting idea for cleanly coding locks on higher level classes, where any extra overhead is unimportant. (I wouldn't use it for a "fundamental" class, such as CircularBuffer. *Especially* not CircularBuffer, whose purpose is to maintain a limited queue, WITHOUT any GC work.)

Comment: .. though to be clear, using the self-disposing `ReaderLockSlim` on `Latest` is fine, as that is a rare operation. It is `Add` operation that would best be done without the extra GC work of allocating/disposing a `WriterLockSlim`. And given that, for consistent coding style, one should stick to try/finally throughout this class.