# A buffer that holds and provides the latest n items

Tags: c#, thread-safety, concurrency, circular-list

I have developed the following code to hold n latest items it has received, and when asked for provide these n latest items.
The interface is:

```
public interface ICircularBuffer<T> {
        void Put(T item);  // put an item
        T[] Read(); // provides the last "n" requests
}
```

The idea is to build a buffer that will hold "n" latest items that have been put and return those items when asked for.

For example:

```
var buf = new ConcurrentBuffer<int>(3); // creates a buffer of size = 3
buf.Put(15);
buf.Put(10);
buf.Put(20);

int[] arr = buf.Read() // returns - 20,10,15

buf.Put(25);
int[] arr = buf.Read() // returns - 25,20,10
```

The implementation uses "locks" and array to represent the circular buffer:

```
public class ConcuurentCircularBuffer<T> : ICircularBuffer<T> {

        private T[] buffer;
        private int last = 0;
        private int sz;
        private object lockObject = new object();

        public ConcuurentCircularBuffer(int sz) {
            // array index starts at 1
            this.sz = sz;
            buffer = new T[sz + 1];
        }

        public void Put(T item) {
            lock (lockObject) {
                last++;
                last = last > sz ? 1 : last;
                buffer[last] = item;
            }
        }

        public T[] Read() {
            T[] arr = new T[sz];

            lock (lockObject) {
                int iterator = 0;
                for (int read = 0; read < sz; read++) {
                    int index = last - iterator;
                    index = index <= 0 ? (sz + index) : index;
                    if (buffer[index] != null) {
                        arr[iterator] = buffer[index];
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                    iterator++;
                }
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }
```

The unit tests I am using to check the performance are as follows:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void TestParallelPut() {
            int sz = 10;
            ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int> buf = new ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int>(sz);

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            ManualResetEventSlim evt = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

            int nTimes = 100000;

            Task[] tasks = new Task[nTimes];
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < nTimes; i++) {
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
                    evt.Wait();
                    buf.Put(i);
                });
            }

            // signal all to proceed
            evt.Set();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);

            watch.Stop();
            double timeMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            TestContext.WriteLine("Buffer size: {0}", sz);
            TestContext.WriteLine("Average time per put: {0} ms, total time taken for {1} parallel requests: {2} ms",timeMs/nTimes,nTimes,timeMs);

    }
```

This test tries to simulate maximum contention, by trying to put all n items in parallel.

The following test, puts n items in parallel, and also continues to read in parallel:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void TestParallelPutAndRead() {
            int sz = 10;
            ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int> buf = new ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int>(sz);

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            ManualResetEventSlim evt = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            ManualResetEventSlim completeEvt = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            int nTimes = 100000;

            Task[] tasks = new Task[nTimes];
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < nTimes; i++) {
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
                    evt.Wait();
                    buf.Put(i);
                });
            }

            // start reading, until told to stop
            Task.Run(() => {
                for(;;) {
                    if (completeEvt.IsSet) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        int[] arr = buf.Read();
                        Assert.IsTrue(arr.Length == sz);
                    }
                }
            });

            // signal all to proceed
            evt.Set();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            completeEvt.Set();

            watch.Stop();
            double timeMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            TestContext.WriteLine("Test ParallelPut and Read - Buffer size: {0}", sz);
            TestContext.WriteLine("Average time per put: {0} ms, total time taken for {1} parallel requests: {2} ms", timeMs / nTimes, nTimes, timeMs);

        }
```

The following test, start "nTasks" in parallel and each task puts nTimes/nTasks. Another tasks keeps reading it as well:

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void TestPutAndNParallelAndRead() {
            int sz = 10;
            ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int> buf = new ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int>(sz);

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            ManualResetEventSlim evt = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            ManualResetEventSlim completeEvt = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
            int nTimes = 1000000;
            int nTasks = 100;

            Task[] tasks = new Task[nTasks];
            watch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < nTasks; i++) {
                tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
                    evt.Wait();
                    for (int n = 0; n < nTimes / nTasks; n++) {
                        buf.Put(i);
                    }
                });
            }

            // start reading, until told to stop
            Task.Run(() => {
                for (;;) {
                    if (completeEvt.IsSet) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        int[] arr = buf.Read();
                        Assert.IsTrue(arr.Length == sz);
                    }
                }
            });

            // signal all to proceed
            evt.Set();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            completeEvt.Set();

            watch.Stop();
            double timeMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
            TestContext.WriteLine("Test Put and {0} Parallel Put and Read - Buffer size: {1}", nTasks,sz);
            TestContext.WriteLine("Average time per put: {0} ms, total time taken for {1} requests: {2} ms", timeMs / nTimes, nTimes, timeMs);

        }
```

The tests results are follows on Windows 7 Enterprise with Intel Core i5-4310U CPU @ 2.00 GHz:

```
Test Name:  TestParallelPut 
TestContext Messages: 
Test ParallelPut - Buffer size: 10 Average time per put: 0.002393078 ms, total time taken for 100000 parallel requests: 239.3078 ms

Test Name:  TestParallelPutAndRead 
Test Outcome:   Passed 
TestContext Messages: Test ParallelPut and Read - Buffer size: 10 Average time per put: 0.002982335 ms, total time taken for 100000 parallel requests:
298.2335 ms


Test Name:  TestPutAndNParallelAndRead 
Test Outcome:   Passed 
TestContext Messages: Test Put and 100 Parallel Put and Read - Buffer size: 10 Average time per put: 0.0003211726 ms, total time taken for 1000000 requests: 321.1726 ms
```

Is there any alternative approach (with better performance) that can be followed to achieve the required functionality?

Please review the code and tests.

Comment: What's the use case for this container?  Is the size 10 used by your tests a realistic size?  You don't empty the buffer when you read from it, is it really OK for two successive reads to return overlapping data sets?

Comment: The size could range from 10 to 1000. No two successive reads should not return overlapping data, every read should get "N" latest items

Comment: @Ngm If you return the N latest items without having added at least N new items in the mean time you will get overlapping data.

Comment: Apologies, it can return overlapping data, the idea is: it should return the "N" latest items (latest one first order).

Comment: @Ngm please update the description in your question to reflect that.

Comment: @forsvarir done, added an example

Comment: Do you require M > 1 concurrent writers and N > 1 concurrent readers?  If you only need one reader and one writer, the ANCIENT, ANCIENT (late 1960s) Control Data Corporation circular buffer does it all without ANY need for mutual exclusion AT ALL.  All you need are atomic word reads and writes.  (The 6600, and its kin and successors, in fact had two physical processors reading and writing.  One read, one wrote.)

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm very interesting info, thank you. Yes I would required M > 1 readers and N > 1 writers. But I suppose then I can try and queue the reads and writes. But it might end up very similar to lock implementations wouldn't it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular Buffer Implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133926/circular-buffer-implementation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Naming**

- There is one 'u' in Concu**u**rentCircularBuffer that wants to be a 'r' --> ConcurrentCircularBuffer
- There is no need to abbreviate name like size (`sz` --> `size`)
- I would call `last` to something more descriptive like `lastIndex`.

**Code Style**

- `sz`, `buffer` and `lockObject` should be read-only.
- There is no need to skip the first array element, just start with 0.
- `iterator` has always the same value as `read`. Therfore you can drop it.

**Behavior**

- The array returned by `Read` has always the same size as the buffer, independend of the actual number of items. To avoid that, consider to change the type of `arr` to `List<T>`.
- If one of the buffer's elements is null, you assume, that the end of the buffer is reached. Therefore: `circularBuffer.Put(null)` would clear the buffer. That is an unexpected behavior. Suggestion: Don't allow to put null values to the buffer (throw ArgumentNullException) and add a method `Clear` if needed.
- When using a primitive type like `int` for `T`, the `Read` method returns an array with the size of the buffer with the default value, even if no item was added. That is also a little bit strange... I suppose you need something like a count property that stores the number of added items.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @JanDotNet's answer:

You can use "less strict" `lock` in your code, specifically [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock(v=vs.110).aspx). As I see from your code, you can execute `Read` in parallel threads but cannot execute `Put` and `Read` in parallel. These classes are exactly for this case and will improve overall performance.

Comment: Depending on the access patterns the higher overhead of RW locks might actually decrease performance. Make sure to benchmark it for your use-case.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, you are right. ReadWriteLock might not improve performance. But even without performance it looks more natural here

Answer (score 8):

You can make your code much simpler if you use a `LinkedList<T>` instead of an array. It has also a much better performance when inserting and removing items in this case which are both *O(1)* operations:

```
public class ConcurrentCircularBuffer<T> : ICircularBuffer<T>
{
    private readonly LinkedList<T> _buffer;
    private int _maxItemCount;

    public ConcurrentCircularBuffer(int maxItemCount)
    {
        _maxItemCount = maxItemCount;
        _buffer = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    public void Put(T item)
    {
        lock (_buffer)
        {
            _buffer.AddFirst(item);
            if (_buffer.Count > _maxItemCount)
            {
                _buffer.RemoveLast();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Read()
    {
        lock(_buffer) { return _buffer.ToArray(); }
    }
}
```

MSDN:

[LinkedList.RemoveLast Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132172(v=vs.110).aspx)

[LinkedList.AddFirst Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132182(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would prefer that solution because the implementaion is simpler. But even if the performance difference isn't significant, I can't imagine that the `LinkedList` has a better performance compared to a raw array buffer.

Comment: +1 It's always astounding to see the difference that a data type can make to the complexity of these things :)

Comment: I agree, I think this implementation is way better. Unless some actual performance issues are encountered, i think readability should come first. You can also use `Queue` instead of `LinkedList`: it has simpler api, IMHO.

Comment: @NikitaB I started with a `Queue` but then you would need to use a `Reverse()` for reading and it can cost some time for larger collections.

Comment: @t3chb0t , ah, yes, I've missed the fact, that last added elements should go first. `LinkedList` is definitely better in that case.

Comment: @t3chb0t, put in the code above is still O(1). We have to enumerate for Read, which both implementations do. I used array instead of linked-list to have better linear read performance (but yes I have not compared it against linked-list)

Comment: In this case the word `Circular` no longer makes sense in the name. Perhaps something like `ConcurrentLimitedBuffer` would be better. Then again, maybe 'Circular' is okay, since it sets expectations about what the class does, regardless of the implementation. Just a thought.

Comment: `_buffer` should already be of `IEnumerable<T>` type, so you can return it without doing `ToArray`

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to add, that for large buffers `Buffer.BlockCopy` (or `Array.Copy` or other similar methods) will give a way better performance, than element-by-element copying.

Also this:

```
// array index starts at 1
buffer = new T[sz + 1];
```

looks like an accident waiting to happen. The entire framework is built around zero-based indexes. I would not recommend having it any other way in your collections. Otherwise it is really easy to make a mistake: your program will have hundreds of arrays flying around, where most of them will be regular arrays, except for that one special array, where you have to skip first element and subtract `1` from `Length` before doing any operations (including LINQ queries!). At least make a custom array class, which would override `Length` and would throw an exception when you access `0` index. Or save yourself a trouble and just use regular array. And add `-1` to index when reading form it.

Answer (score 2):

Just scratching the surface of your code

1. Your interface `ICircularBuffer<T>` breaks SRP- Interface Segregration. This inteface is responsible for Putting and Reading items .
2. There is a lot of repetition in your test methods. One thing you have to avoid in pogramming is **DRY** . Instead of defining `ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int>`, `Stopwatch`, `ManualResetEventSlim` e.g

   ```
   [TestInitialize]
   public void Initialize() {
       int sz = 10;
       ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int> buf = new ConcuurentCircularBuffer<int>(sz);
       Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();;
       ManualResetEventSlim evt=new ManualResetEventSlim(false);;
       ManualResetEventSlim completeEvt=new ManualResetEventSlim(false);;      
   }
   ```
3. You could call a TestCleanup to set your objects to null e.g

   ```
   [TestCleanup()]
   public void Cleanup()
   { /* assign null to the objects */ }
   ```
4. Your naming convention for your test methods can be improved. Most unit testers use this convention-[Naming Standard for Unit test by Roy Osherove](http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html)

   ```
   [UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior]
   ```
5. A possible bug that could occur - If a negative number was passed as a parameter to the constructor e.g -1

   ```
   public ConcuurentCircularBuffer(int sz) {
       // array index starts at 1
       this.sz = sz;
       buffer = new T[sz + 1];
   }
   ```

   you want to check if a buffer length > 0 - then some computations should not be performed.
6. Before progressing into `parallelPut` and `ParallelRead` you should test one, two, three items are added or read to the buffer. In Nunit you can use the `Assert` class to check if the items returned are equal to what's stored in the buffer.

Comment: The OP is using the Microsoft testing framework, however `Assert` is still be available.

Comment: 5: `int` is a value type and so cannot be null. Testing for negative numbers could be a great idea though.

Comment: @RobH yeah right

Comment: @TolaniJaiye-Tikolo: Interface Segregration means, that (big) interfaces should be splitted to become more client specific. Therefore, it is OK to have multiple methods (or responsibilities) in one interface. See also ISet, IList, ... from .net Framework.

Comment: @JanDotNet thanks mates I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Emm, so you are basically saying, that every .Net collection breaks SRP? I'm not so sure about that.